# KeyError checking magnitud on Python

Tags: python, big-o

In Python, analyzing same operations(same methods) i observe that in different types of data, list and dictionary in this case, they have different efficiency (Big-O). For example:

```
# dictionary O(1) vs list O(n)

import timeit
import random

for i in range(10000, 1000001, 20000):
    t = timeit.Timer("random.randrange(%d) in x" % i,
                 "from __main__ import random,x")
    # not defining function, use the list x object in our test

    x = list(range(i))
    tempo_list = t.timeit(number=1000)
    x = {j: None for j in range(i)}
    tempo_dictionary = t.timeit(number=1000)
    print("%d,%10.3f,%10.3f" % (i, tempo_list, tempo_dictionary))
```

Similarly but with the operator *del*

```
remove = timeit.Timer("del x[0]", "from __main__ import x")
for i in range(1000000, 100000001, 1000000):
    x = list(range(i))
    rlist = remove.timeit(number=1000)
    x = {j: None for j in range(i)}
    rdict = remove.timeit(number=1000)
    print("%15.5f, %15.5f" % (rlist, rdict))
```

But I have a problem...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jrr/.config/sublime-text 3/Packages/User/Python/example.py", line 9, in <module>
    rdict = remove.timeit(number=1000)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 202, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: I think a lot of this is symptomatic of mutating the dictionary during iteration. Are you timing `del` or the lookup of the element itself?

Comment: I'm focusing in *del*, compare the performance of the operator of lists and dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've deleted `0` from the dictionary, so on subsequent calls, there is no `x[0]`:

```
x = {0: None, 1: None}
del x[0]
# x = {1: None}
del x[0]
# KeyError
```

I'd suggest doing some sort of function where you go through a list of keys `x.keys()` and you delete each one subsequently. Whether or not you can do that in `Timer`, I'm sure someone much more skilled with that module can speak to better than I can.

As a note, a list lookup with an *index* like `x[1115]` is of O(1), not O(N)

Comment: Thanks,  but I'm not sure with your note about efficiency. My example is the same operation, exactly the call belonging (in). In some cases this operation, as well as obtaining and assigning items, can be O(n). I use it as O(1), 
i'm right?

Comment: If you are checking that an element is `in` a list, then yes, that would be O(n)